# 403 error after adding product to cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating e-commerce site using woocommerce plugin. Everything works well until adding a product to cart on my site. Then, if I go to the cart page - everything breaks down. Only thing that shows up is

```
Error occurred: 403 - forbidden 
Apache Server at: s1062803-15589.home-whs.pl
```

Now I have no access to the site at all, even to wp-admin site. What can I do?

Comment: Hi Adam, have you solved your issue? I'm struggling this right now and can't figure it out :(

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem by contacting with my hosting operator. They changed configuration of .htaccess file. It looks like it was blocking some functions of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Solution -  it looks like the problem comes from a .htaccess file on a server. It was blocking some parts of the site. I contacted my hosting operator and they configured the file. Now my site works very well.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes firewall and something like mod_security make this problem. if you are host administrator try to disable them.